# Is there a way to use mode in an xsl:if test?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, mode

I've been learning to use the mode attribute with XSLT and was wondering if there's a way to test for it within a template, such as in an xsl:if statement? I've only seen it used at the xsl:template level and maybe that's the only way. Say I want to add a "../" in front of a path attribute (@href), but only if mode="print":

```
     <xsl:template name="object" mode="#all">
        <img>
         <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:if test="mode='print'"><xsl:text>../</xsl:text></xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
     </xsl:template>
```

I'm calling apply-templates with and without the mode="print" set from various other templates.

Of course I can make a new template with mode="print" but then I'd have to maintain two templates.

Or maybe there's a better way to do this? Thanks for the help. - Scott

Comment: What processor are you working with? If it is Saxon, there is a Saxon extension for this, called [`saxon:current-mode-name()`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/functions/currentmode.html). Unfortunately, it is not available in Saxon HE.

Comment: What's exactly wrong with having two templates? If you write them without duplicating functionality but with one being generic and the other one being specific calling the first one with a path prefix as parameter it shouldn't be so bad.

Comment: My templates can be complex, and with only that one variation it seems inefficient to maintain two. For instance, if I decided to change select="@href" to select="@id", I'd have to do it in two places. That's a simple example, but with more complex structures it can get messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it yet. One approach can be-

```
<xsl:template match="/">

   <xsl:apply-templates select="something" mode="a">
      <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'a'" tunnel="yes"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="something" mode="b">
      <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'b'" tunnel="yes"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>
```

and then in the match-

```
<xsl:template match="blah" mode="a b">
   <xsl:param name="mode" tunnel="yes"/>

   <xsl:if test="$mode='a'">
     <!-- Do Something -->
   </xsl:if>

   <xsl:if test="$mode='b'">
     <!-- Do Something -->
   </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the current mode, but you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="object" mode="#all">
  <xsl:param name="print" select="false()"/>

  <!-- Your code here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object" mode="print">
  <xsl:next-match>
    <xsl:with-param name="print" select="true()"/>
  </xsl:next-match>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how I'd get my xsl:if in there...


          <xsl:param name="print" select="false()"/>


          <xsl:if test="$print='false()'">

           ... do something ...

          </xsl:if>

          <xsl:if test="print='true()'">

           ... do something else ...
          </xsl:if>

Comment: @ScottStark That's what the `print` parameter is for.