# XSL template how to determine dynamically which mode was matched

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Suppose an XSLT template matches an element in two modes, is it possible to figure out dynamically which mode triggered the match?

In pseudo xslt:

```
template match="elementname" mode="a b"  
    if %mode% = 'a' then do something
    if %mode% = 'b' then do something
```

(this would be useful in situations where 90% of the template is identical for both modes, but in one case an additional attribute needs to be created)

(this question was already asked [Is there a way to use mode in an xsl:if test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370734/is-there-a-way-to-use-mode-in-an-xslif-test) My mistake for not spotting that. Thanks for the replies anyway)

Comment: Saxon has an extension function for this: http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/current-mode-name

Comment: BTW, the situation you describe can be handled much more elegantly by having two separate templates, with one template calling the other.

Comment: @michael.hor257k unfortunately I use Saxon HE (not PE or EE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just use a parameter:

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ab">
    <xsl:with-param name="sw">a</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:apply-templates>


<xsl:template select="elementname" mode="a b">
  <xsl:param name="sw" />
  <xsl:if test="$sw='a'>do this</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```